# Regex With Negative Lookahead For Word

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

Using a PCRE flavour, I'm trying to come up with a regex that will match a URL as long as it does not contain `/foo` after the `/songs/{id}`

```
/songs/902   => Match
/songs/902/   => Match
/songs/902/foo   => No Match
/songs/902/foo/201/bar   => No Match
/songs/902/bar   => Match
```

This is what I have so far `^\/songs\/.+(?!\/foo).*$` but it seems to match all the given examples.

Comment: Use `~/songs/\d+(?!.*/foo\b)~`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^\/songs\/(?!.*\/foo).+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/q7wIWF/1). The `^\/songs\/` locates `/songs/` at the start, then `(?!.*\/foo)` check if `/foo` is present later in the string, and `.+` matches what remains.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `/songs/.+(?!\/foo)` where negative lookahead is applied after greedy `.+`, that after `/songs/`, will just match everything including `/foo` till end and then it will satisfies lookahead assertion. You need to apply lookahead assertion just after matching `/songs/` or `/songs/<digits>`.

You may use this regex in `php` with a negative lookahead:

```
~/songs/\d+(?!.*/foo\b)~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c4PYBa/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `/songs/\d+`: Match `/songs/` followed by 1+ digits
- `(?!.*/foo\b)`: Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have `/foo` ahead of the current position.

**Code:**

```
$re = '~/songs/\d+(?!.*/foo\b)~';
preg_match_all($re, $input, $matches);

// Print the match result
var_dump($matches[0]);
```